# Zooming page (ctr+ ctr-), collapsed template

Tags: css, templates, css-float

I have the page layout of the three columns of fixed width.
See the following snippet of HTML and CSS

At some resolutions the monitor (especially in the firefox), when I am scaling page (CTR-), template page is collapsing.
I can not find a solution to this problem.

As an alternative, I reduced width of 1 px for div.right-wrapper and div.right-column.
But that not exactly to specifications.

Does anyone have ideas?
Thanks.

```
<div class="main_content three-column">
      <div class="main_content_inner">
         <div class="left-column">
            <h1>Left column</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="right-wrapper">
            <div class="content-column">
               <h1>Content column</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="right-column">
               <h1>Right column</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="clr"></div>
   </div>
</div>



.main_content.three-column {
    background: #fff;
    width: 998px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main_content.three-column .main_content_inner {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.left-column { 
    width: 199px;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 0;  
    border-right: 1px solid #e8eaec;
    float: left; 
    background: red;
}

.right-wrapper { 
    width: 768px; 
    border-left: 1px solid #e8eaec;
    margin-left: -1px;  
    float: left;
}

.content-column {
    width: 558px;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: green;
}

.right-column {
   width: 190px;
   float: left;
   padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: blue;
}

.clr {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main_content.three-column h1 {
    font: normal 24px/12px Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;    
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not for now, but this is eventually where we are going: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a layout that scales use relative dimensions, such as em or ex, instead of absolute dimensions, such as px.

I recommend setting the html element to a font-size of 10px, so that everywhere 1em = 10px until you change the font size:

```
html {font-size: 10px}
```

Then if you want a div to be 993px just set it to 99.3em.  Now your layout will scale.

Answer (score 0):

I found next optimal solution for a particular case.

1) Removed the block    right-wrapper

2) Added styles for the block

```
div.content-column {
   border-left: 1px solid #e8eaec;
   margin-left: -1px;
   padding-right: 0;
}
```

3) Added styles for the block

```
div.right-column {
   float: right;
}
```

I set the next widths for blocks:

```
div.left-column {
   border-right: 1px solid #E8EAEC;
   float: left;
   padding: 15px 10px 15px 0;
   width: 199px;
}

div.content-column {
   border-left: 1px solid #E8EAEC;
   float: left;
   margin-left: -1px;
   padding: 15px 0 15px 10px;
   width: 558px;
}

div.right-column {
   float: right;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 190px;
}
```

Due to the 10-pixel spacing between the    content-column    and    right-column
    template is not collapsing when zooming.

Comment my solution, please.

Thank you all for participating.